# trigger js alerts from es6 in iOS safari not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, mobile-safari, es6-class

I have a website that triggers an alert when items are added to the cart. I'm using javascript ES6, html5. 
I'm dynamically creating bootstrap styled cards with menu items on the page and a add to cart button. when the add to cart button is pressed an alert is triggered. 
The alert attempts to trigger on iOS 13.x.x safari but doesn't show. I attempted to set a timeout, but that didn't work. It has to be the way it's being called. I really don't know what to try next. I read that user navigation (back, forward) can break alerts. In the 'addEventListener' of the 'btn' towards the bottom of this horrific method is where the problem arises. Why is this not working on safari mobile?

```
createMenuCard(menu){
            var heading = document.getElementById("concession-name");
            heading.innerText = menu.menus.menu.concessionName;

            var card = null;
            var body = null;
            var lsgroup = null;

            for(var i = 0; i < menu.menus.menu.categories.length; i++){

                for(var j = 0; j < menu.menus.menu.categories[i].menuItems.length; j++){

                    this.card = document.createElement('div');
                    this.card.className = 'card';
                    this.card.setAttribute('id', this.uuidv4());
                    this.card.setAttribute('style', 'width: 20rem;');
                    this.body = document.createElement('div');
                    this.body.className = 'card-body';

                    var title = document.createElement('div');
                    title.className = 'card-title';
                    title.innerText = menu.menus.menu.categories[i].menuItems[j].name;
                    this.body.appendChild(title);
                    this.lsgroup = document.createElement('div');
                    this.lsgroup.className = "list-group";
                    this.body.appendChild(this.lsgroup);

                    for(var k = 0; k < menu.menus.menu.categories[i].menuItems[j].subItems.length; k++){


                        if(menu.menus.menu.categories[i].menuItems[j].subItems[k].name === "")
                        {
                            var id = this.uuidv4();

                            var input = document.createElement("input");
                            input.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
                            input.setAttribute("name", "");
                            input.setAttribute("id", id);
                            input.setAttribute("value", menu.menus.menu.categories[i].menuItems[j].name);
                            input.setAttribute("price", menu.menus.menu.categories[i].menuItems[j].subItems[k].price);
                            this.lsgroup.appendChild(input);
                            // label
                            var label = document.createElement("label");
                            label.className = "list-group-item";
                            label.setAttribute("for", id);
                            label.innerText = menu.menus.menu.categories[i].menuItems[j].subItems[k].price + "  " + menu.menus.menu.categories[i].menuItems[j].name;
                            this.lsgroup.appendChild(label);
                        } 
                        else 
                        {
                            var id = this.uuidv4();
                            // input
                            var input = document.createElement("input");
                            input.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
                            input.setAttribute("name", "");
                            input.setAttribute("id", id);
                            input.setAttribute("value", menu.menus.menu.categories[i].menuItems[j].subItems[k].name);
                            input.setAttribute("price", menu.menus.menu.categories[i].menuItems[j].subItems[k].price);
                            this.lsgroup.appendChild(input);
                            // label
                            var label = document.createElement("label");
                            label.className = "list-group-item";
                            label.setAttribute("for", id);
                            label.innerText = menu.menus.menu.categories[i].menuItems[j].subItems[k].price + "  " +menu.menus.menu.categories[i].menuItems[j].subItems[k].name;
                            this.lsgroup.appendChild(label);
                        }
                    }

                    var btn = document.createElement('a');
                    btn.setAttribute("href", "#"); // javascript:toCart()
                    btn.addEventListener("click", (e)=> {

                        var inputs = e.path[2].querySelector("div > div.list-group").getElementsByTagName("input");
                        var description = e.path[2].querySelector("div > div.card-title").innerText;

                        for(var l = 0; l < inputs.length; l++){
                            if(inputs[l].checked === true){

                                var obj = {
                                    option : inputs[l].value,
                                    price : inputs[l].getAttribute("price")
                                };

                                setTimeout(function(){
                                    window.alert("Added: " + description + " to cart");
                                }, 300);
                                //window.alert("Added: " + description + " to cart");
                                description += " " + obj.option;
                                var appItem = new AppItems(description, obj.price, 1);
                                cart.addItem(appItem); 
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    btn.className = "btn btn-primary";
                    btn.innerText = "Add To Cart";
                    this.body.appendChild(btn);
                    this.card.appendChild(this.body);
                    var container = document.getElementById('cards');
                    container.appendChild(this.card);
                }
            }


            var chk = document.getElementById("checkout");
            chk.addEventListener("click", (e)=> {

                cart.save();
                window.open("./cart.html","_self");
            });
       }
```